# Camera shaking on rotating player while crouching in unity

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine

I am having a problem with the camera following the player. When the player moves, the camera shakes and this effect is more noticeable when the player is in the crouched position. I am using root motion for the player with animations by mixamo.

Player Script:

```
Transform cameraT;
void Start () {
cameraT = Camera.main.transform;
}
void FixedUpdate ()
{
float sideMotion = Input.GetAxis("SideMotion");
float straightMotion= Input.GetAxis("StraightMotion");
if (Mathf.Abs(sideMotion) > 0 || Mathf.Abs(straightMotion) > 0)
     {
         transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, 
cameraT.eulerAngles.y);

     }
}
```

Camera Script:

```
public float distanceFromPlayer=2f;

 public float mouseSensitivity=6;

 public Transform player;

 public Vector2 pitchConstraint= new Vector2(-30,80);

 Vector3 rotationSmoothVelocity;
 Vector3 currentRotation;
 public float rotationSmoothTime = 0.2f;

 float yaw; //Rotation around the vertical axis is called yaw

 float pitch; //Rotation around the side-to-side axis is called pitch

 private void LateUpdate()
 {
     yaw += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
     pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
     pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, pitchConstraint.x, pitchConstraint.y);

     currentRotation = Vector3.SmoothDamp
         (currentRotation, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotationSmoothVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);


     transform.eulerAngles = currentRotation;

     transform.position = player.position - transform.forward * distanceFromPlayer;
 }
```

For public transform I just added an empty game object to player chest level and parented it to the player. I got the rotating camera smoothly trick from an online tutorial but that exact thing won't work on player rotation though.

A character controller is attached to player without any rigidbody or collider.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to use Lerp on the camera in order to smooth its motion from one position to another. The Scripting API has a good example of [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

So in your case, you could add a public variable for smoothing position as well. Something like positionSmoothTime. Then make a "Desired Position" variable, we'll call it destPosition.

```
Vector3 destPosition = player.position - transform.forward * distanceFromPlayer;

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, destPosition, positionSmoothTime);
```

This should effectively smooth it to where the stuttering should go away. Another thing that will help that someone else mentioned is using a part of the body that moves less (Like the head) as the target. This combined with the Lerp function will give you a smooth camera movement.

Another large help would be to move things into the [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) function. The reason being is [FixedUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) doesn't get called every frame. So you could potentially get stutter as a result. If you move everything into [Update()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) it will update every frame and help smooth things out. If you do this though you will need to multiply all movement by [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) as shown in the example below.

```
Vector3 destPosition = (player.position - transform.forward * distanceFromPlayer) * Time.deltaTime;
```

For more examples, check the links to each function to see Unity's documentation on it. It has examples of everything I've shown here.

Comment: thanks that helped a lot, but, still after trying all those player stutters when jumping side ways. :/

Comment: So I didn't catch this yesterday but it may be caused by the way it's updating. Try moving the player movement out of fixedUpdate and put it in Update. Then, multiply the movement by time.deltaTime. I'll update my answer in a couple hours to show it better.

Comment: yeah I will try it right now. Should I post video too?

Comment: Maybe, but I just updated my post, let me know if that does it.

Comment: Yep, moving them to update reduced stuttering. But, it is not fully gone though :/ . But, yeah thanks for your support too.

Comment: Maybe post another video to help us understand what's happening.

Comment: Should I not use camera movement in In LateUpdate method?

Comment: You could, sorry, I thought they were both in FixedUpdate, I didn't see that the camera used LateUpdate(). In that case it's still getting called every frame, just after everything else. Typically, I consider the Camera and Player movements important enough to keep in Update(). I only use LateUpdate for things that are less important or that need to run after everything else.

Comment: Here is the doc on [LateUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

Comment: Yep, that's why I used lateupdate with camera according to doc. Moreover I also tried it in update method, but it is stuttering more there. And here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi8WWniBQaw

Comment: Okay, so that's not really a stutter per se, that's more like the camera isn't looking at the target anymore. I'll look over the code a bit more in unity and see.

Comment: You saw the player shaking a bit while rotating while walking and crouching? Is not that a lag? And I am glad you are helping me out. IT is rare xD

Answer (score 0):

If the camera is tightly attached to the player gameobject, as a child object with a fixed relative position, will shake when using Root Motion.

Changing the follow camera to a CineMachine  Virtual camera, set to follow the player and look at the player, we have also a "Follow the Player camera", but now we can damp the camera shaking by increasing **Yaw Damping** in the virtual camera settings, as shown in the image below.

[image]

Another way to eliminate the camera shaking, if the animation type is Humanoid:

[image]

is by checking the **Root Transform Rotation**, **Bake Into Pose**:

[image]

This will disable rotation of the character while moving. However for some clips, this might be undesirable.

Let's say we have a walk and turn clip. Disabling **Root Transform Rotation** will ruin the turning of the character, forcing it to clumsy keep going forward.

The Inspector hints if it is ok to disable rotation with a green/yellow/red light in **loop match** field.